# Understand the energy level of "oxygen hole" created by substitutional Al doping in TiO2

Tags: electronic-structure, doping

By substituting a Ti atom in anatase $\text{TiO}_2$ lattice with a Al atom, an oxygen hole $\text{O}^-$ will be created considering a formal charge of +4 for Ti, -2 for O and +3 for Al .

In this paper "[Intrinsic Oxygen Vacancy and Extrinsic Aluminum Dopant Interplay: A Route to the Restoration of Defective TiO2](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jp407736f)", the authors applied the method of DFT+*U* to investigate the energy level of such oxygen hole. By increasing the *U* value, the energy level of oxygen hole was gradually raised from the top of the valance band of $\text{TiO}_2$ to somewhere near the bottom of the conduction band. The authors stated that the reason to increase the *U* value is for localizing the oxygen hole (displaying a rather localized charge density in real space).

**My confusion is**: Why it is necessary for the oxygen hole to be localized?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but just came today to check how things are going? Did you figure out the answer? Are you still working on this? Let us know!